reverse proxy multiple server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location /quicklinks {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

Issue:

When I access http://a.com/, the Next.js app loads without any issues.

When I try to access http://a.com/quicklinks, the page fails to load and I get the following error in the browser console:
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in main_5454354.js in console .
What I have tried:

Accessing http://localhost:3001/quicklinks directly works without issues.

Confirmed that the Nginx configuration is reloaded after changes.


What could be causing this error when accessing /quicklinks on a.com



Most likely your backend app listening on port 3001 requests the main_5454354.js file without /quicklinks prefix. Therefore this request gets handled with your first location, returning 404 Not Found HTML page since there are no such file for the backend app listening on port 3000. This error page starts with the <html> tag, giving you the Unexpected token '<'... error. Whatever the backend app listening on port 3001 is, it shoukd be set up to use the /quicklinks prefix for its assets.

Since you add the reactjs tag to your question, this link may be of interest to you: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths
